# ¿como pasar variables entre componentes livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, component, laravel-livewire, livewire

tengo un componente livewire llamado ShowProcesos, con el cual muestro, creo, edito y elimino "procesos" usando un modal en la ruta /procesos. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] quiero seleccionar un proceso y que se me muestre su información, pero quiero usar otra vista (porque quiero agregarle otras cosas a ese proceso), no quiero usar un modal. Esto es lo que hice: creé otra ruta "/verproceso" relacionada al componente ExpandProcesos, en la vista de show-procesos puse un botón:
`<button class="btn bg-success" wire:click="expandproceso({{$proceso->id}})">Ver proceso</button>`

El botón llama a la función expandproceso en el componente ShowProcesos, con la cual intento pasarle el id del proceso al otro componente ExpandProcesos mediante un evento y redirecciono a la otra ruta:

```
public function expandproceso($id_proceso){
        $findproceso = Procesos::find($id_proceso);
        $this->findproceso = $findproceso;
        $this->emit('render', $findproceso->id);
        return redirect()->route('verproceso');
    }
```

En el componente ExpandProceso intento capturar el evento y el id en la función render para luego buscar ese id:

```
public $proceso;
    protected $listeners = ['render' => 'render'];

    public function render(Procesos $proceso)
    {
        $this->proceso = Procesos::find($proceso);
        return view('livewire.procesos.expand-procesos');
    }
```

En la vista expand-proceso hago un foreach de $proceso para mostrar los datos del proceso pero no carga nada, leí la documentación y traté de hacerlo a como estaba allí, pero no me quedó muy claro. ¿cual es la manera mas facil de pasarle el id del proceso desde el componente ShowProcesos al componente ExpandProceso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías crear un componente completo para esa vista y desde el boton redireccionar a ese componente mas o menos así.

```
<a href="{{ route('ruta', $proceso->id) }}">Ver proceso</a>
```

Anterior a eso debes de registrar el componente en tu archivo de rutas para que no vayas a tener problemas.

```
Route::get('/proceso/{id}', Componente::class);
```

Posteriormente en el nuevo componente podrias cargar el id desde el metodo *mount*

```
public $proceso;
  
     public function mount($proceso_id){
       $this->proceso = Proceso::find($proceso_id);
     }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.procesos.expand-procesos');
    }
```

Con esto ya tienes disponible la variable proceso en tu componente completo.

Comment: Hola amigo, de esta manera se envia el id por la ruta, pero la función mount no lo lee, sale este error: Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [ <required> $proceso_id ]] in class App\Http\Livewire\Procesos\ExpandProcesos

Comment: Como tienes tu ruta?

Comment: así tengo la ruta verprocesos: Route::get('/verproceso', ExpandProcesos::class)->name('verproceso');

Comment: Te hace falta el parametro a la ruta. Route::get(“proceso/{id}”,componente)

Comment: gracias bro me funcionó, puedes colocar eso en la respuesta para marcala como solución :)

Comment: Listo, edite la respuesta.